# How to update state with dispatch before render in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am begginer in React with Redux and I am having a problem that I dont understand how to solve.
I am coding some simple snake game. I when I press some key arrow I want the snake to move accordingly. But the render is happening before dispatch updates the state.

Here is the code:

```
function App1() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const init = useSelector(state => state.snake)

    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfOutOfBorders()
    }, [init])

    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
        console.log("_______________")
        e = e || window.event;
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 38:
            dispatch({
              type: "UP"
            });
            moveSnake()
            break;
          case 40:
            dispatch({
              type: "DOWN"
            });
            moveSnake()
            break;
          case 37:
            dispatch({
              type: "LEFT"
            });
            moveSnake()
            break;
          case 39:
            dispatch({
              type: "RIGHT"
            });
            moveSnake()
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
    }
    

    const moveSnake = () => {
        let dots = [...init.snakeDots];
        let head = dots[dots.length - 1];
        let direction = init.direction
        switch (direction) {
          case 'RIGHT':
            console.log("into move", direction)
            head = [head[0] + 2, head[1]];
           break;
          case 'LEFT':
            console.log("into move", direction)
            head = [head[0] - 2, head[1]];
            break;
          case 'DOWN':
            console.log("into move", direction)
            head = [head[0], head[1] + 2];
            break;
          case 'UP':
            console.log("into move", direction)
            head = [head[0], head[1] - 2];
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        dots.push(head);
        dots.shift();
        dispatch({
          type:"MOVE_SNAKE",
          dots
        })
    }
```

And here is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    speed:200,
    direction: 'RIGHT',
    snakeDots: [
      [0,0],
      [2,0]
    ]
  }


export default function (state=initialState , action){
    const {type, payload} = action;
    //console.log("dots", action.dots)
    console.log("type", type)

    switch(type){
        case 'UP':
            console.log("up");
            return{
                ...state,
                direction:'UP'
            }
        case 'DOWN':
            console.log("down");
            return{
                ...state,
                direction:'DOWN'
        }
        case 'LEFT':
            console.log("left");
            return{
                ...state,
                direction:'LEFT'
            }
        case 'RIGHT':
            console.log("right");
            return{
                ...state,
                direction:'RIGHT'
            }
        case 'MOVE_SNAKE':
            return{
                ...state,
                snakeDots:action.dots    
            }
        case 'RESET':
            return{
                speed:200,
                direction: 'RIGHT',
                snakeDots: [
                  [0,0],
                  [2,0]
                ]
                
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This is what appears in console after I press RIGHT, then DOWN. As you can see, what is passed inside dispatch is the correct key (DOWN) but when move_snake() is executed the state still contains (RIGHT) and moves wrongly. How to solve this?

If some additional info is necessary, please tell me.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing here, cause I have not used Redux in ages, but maybe a race condition? Your `moveSnake()` executes before the state is updated by the dispatcher? Maybe instead of manually executing `moveSnake()` try running it from an useEffect?

Comment: Hey, yes, that is what is happening. If I try to move the moveSnake() to useEffect it simply keeps moving non-stop... I am not sure if that is expected

Comment: That is because it's running in a loop. `moveSnake` causes state update, which in turn causes `useEffect` to run, which in turn causes `moveSnake` to run again. You have some logics to figure out, have fun and good luck :).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the reducer

```
 case 'MOVE_SNAKE':
        return{
            ...state,
            snakeDots:payload.dots  //action.dots   
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just tried but it didnt solve the problem :(

Comment: unfortunately :( . Now I changed my answer, Hope it will work :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didnt solve as well :(